# How to Get property values from Shared Object in client's load event?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I am using shared object to share data between two users. First user connect to shared object and set some value in shared object. Please consider that second user has not connected with the shared object yet.

Now when second user connects to the server and try to get that property set by first user, he could get shared object but could not get properties of Shared object set by first user. I observed few times that Second user can get these properties within "Sync" event between two users. But I would like to get these values for Second user in any stage (i.e. in load event etc.). Whenever Second user tries to get the property of Shared object, the object will reset the actual property value and then return reset value.

Anyone faced such issue while using shared object between two users. If so, I would appreciate if you could let me know your suggestions for following questions:
1) Is there any way to get all the properties of shared object before sync event called, as I want to get it immediately when second user connect to the application and perform next task based on the values stored in shared object.
2) Is it possible for second user to check whether any property has been set by first user? So that second user can use the property instead of reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Give you a citation from adobe docs:
"The SharedObject class is used to read and store limited amounts of data on a user's computer or on a server.(...)To use remote shared objects, you need Adobe Flash Media Server"

Do you have a server that supports that technology?